# From C to Assembly jge and jg?

Tags: c, assembly, x86

Does jg and jge execute or jump to the following label if the second register in the statement eg., cmpl %esi, **%edi** is greater than or equal to (or only greater than) the first register **%esi**? And is the result of which one is greater stored in the second register and used to determine if jump executes the consecutive label?

sum1.c

```
 int sum(int first, int last)
 {
      int sum = 0;
      int in_between;
      for (in_between = first; in_between <= last; in_between++)
      {
           sum += in_between;
      }
      return sum;
 }
```

sum1.s:

```
    .file   "sum1.c"
    .text
.globl sum
    .type   sum, @function
sum:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    %edi, %edx ; puts first into in_between
    movl    $0, %eax ; sets sum to zero
    cmpl    %esi, %edi ;compares first and last, checking if first– last < 0
    jg      .L3 ; jumps to .L3 if first is greater than last, otherwise 
 ;executes .L6
.L6:
    addl    %edx, %eax ;adds in_between to sum
    addl    $1, %edx ; increments in_between
    cmpl    %edx, %esi ; makes the comparison between in_between and last, 
    ;last < in_between
    jge     .L6 ; jumps to .L6 if last is greater than or equal to 
    ;in_between. (the result jump uses is stored in last).    
.L3:
    rep
    ret ;returns the value stored in %eax register.
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   sum, .-sum
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)"
    .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: Yes, but the result of the comparison is stored in the flags register. `cmp` doesn't modify arguments.

Comment: Okay so jg or jge jumps if the second register is greater than the first which were used in cmpl, and the result is stored in the flags register.  Thank you!

Comment: Not the jump, the `cmp`. The jump just looks at the flags (it doesn't care what set them). See the instruction set reference and the basic architecture manual.

Comment: The result of the comparison is stored in the flags register, which is *then* used to decide if a jump (branch) is to be taken. The comparison may set several flags, and the jump condition uses *specific* flags to make its condition. So the context of say signed or unsigned comparison is made not in the flags setting, but the flag testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CPU updates the processor status (PS sometimes PSL) register after [nearly] every instruction. The CMPL instruction does an implicit subtraction and updates the values of the PS rester. You'd get the same effect if you did a SUBL instruction, except that SUBL puts the result in the destination operand while CMPL does not.

The Jxx instructions conditionally branch depending upon the value of the PS register.

Comment: x86's flags are [in a register called EFLAGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register) (or `RFLAGS` for the 64-bit version, but the upper 32 bits are all reserved).  What are you talking about with PS / PSL?

Comment: @PeterCordes: Pulls out the VAX and PDP11 the PSW (2 16-bit registers one for program status and one for current processor status). The processor status includes the flags. Both together make up the PSL. He was probably using them in a more general sense.